# Upgrading to rails 5, mongodb as database

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-4.2, rails-upgrade

I am upgrading my rails version to 5.0 from 4.2. App uses `mongoDB` database.

Upgraded mongoid version to 6.3.0.

Do I have to create `application_record.rb` as we do for other activerecord databases, and inherit ApplicationRecord in all models? Should the application_record structure be followed here?

Asking because here models do not inherit but `include Mongoid::Document`.

Pardon me if I am not clear..

Comment: No, you don't _have_ to do that.